# Space is taken as null in sqlloader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, oracle12c

In my data file I have

```
12345678  Vis1  
12345679  Vis2
```

in the control file I have

```
load data
Append
into table MY_TABLE    
TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (
    NBR position(1:8),
    COL1 position(9:11),
    NAME position(13:18)
    )
```

In db COL1 is a not null field. 
The sqllrd is failing by throwing the message

```
    Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE", column COL1.
    ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"."COL1")
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: But what is the problem? What do you wish to insert in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're in need of [preserve blanks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1224) option.

The following change will do the trick

```
load data
Append
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table MY_TABLE
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
NBR position(1:8),
COL1 position(9:11),
NAME position(13:18)
)
```

Comment: I've added the change to do preserve blanks

Comment: @VishnudevK you can add a answer with the complete code instead of editing this one.